# Empty many folders into into single folder?

Tags: files, terminal

I've tried Googling this but I only get answers relevant to Windows.

I've got a series of folders, for the sake of example I'll say `~/Downloads/abc` `~/Downloads/def` `~/Downloads/ghi` etc.

What I would like to do, is empty the contents of each folder into a central folder, whether that be `~/Downloads`, `~/Downloads/xyz`, it doesn't particularly matter. However, I can't seem to figure out any way to practically do this.

Typing it out, I'm not sure if it makes sense, so I'll provide a visual example.

```
Downloads | Downloads
├abc      | ├abc
│└foo.txt > ├def
└def      | ├foo.txt
 └bar.txt | └bar.txt
```

Oh, and one more thing, I use Thunar for a file browser. I imagine this is at least  doable directly from the terminal, but if there's a way to do it in Thunar as well, that would be just as good to know. Thanks!

Comment: If you call your directories "folders", that may explain why you keep finding Windows answers...

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
cd ~/Downdload
zmv '*/(*)(#qD)' '$2'
```

You could also do `mv -i -- */*(D) .`, but using `zmv` has the advantage of erroring out in case of conflict (like when there's both a `abc/file` and `def/file`)  **before** it starts moving files.

To remove empty dirs afterwards:

```
rmdir -- *(D/^F)
```